# Subfloat figures in latex

Tags: latex

I am inputting a bunch of figures in Latex using

```
\begin{figure}[h]
   \centering
   \subfloat
```

etc.

How do I get the subfloat figures to go to the next page? What I mean is, I'm inputting a ton of figures so it'll definitely be more than one page but if I do separate figures for each the a, b, c, d, etc. for the captions will change, so ideally I'd like one enormous figure with a bunch of subfloats a through z on different pages - how do you do that? Right now, I simply can't see the subfloat figures that stretch over the page, so I'll need to get another page somehow.

Answer (score 5):

Separate the figures into batches that fit on one page and in the figure environments after the first put

```
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```

which will decrease the figure counter making it the same as for the previous bunch and then also add

```
\addtocounter{subfigure}{N}
```

where N is the number of subfigs that you have already placed, which will start the subfig counter from the correct value.

More on the subfigure package [here (PDF)](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf).

Comment: +1 Nice solution! I'm still wondering though if someone can come up with something that requires no adaptations to the numbering :).

Comment: Well, messing around with the numbering of the various internal counters of LaTeX is the most common thing to do right after messing around with the various lengths (indentations, margins, spacings etc) ;-). There's probably a way to do this by directly messing with the figure environment, but from a coding perspective that would be much harder than just adjusting some numbers.